# Did I support Canonical financially, when I bought the BQ Aquaris?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, canonical

I love the phone. I love the company. I certainly love Ubuntu. Lately I've been feeling bad just taking and not giving. So did I give a little back, when I bought the phone?